Why GoLang context with timeout not working correctly?
Why GoLang context with timeout not working correctly?
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func test1(ctx context.Context) {
    fmt.Println("Print2")
}

func test(ctx context.Context) {
    t1 := time.Now()

    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("Print1")
    fmt.Println(time.Since(t1))
    test1(ctx)
    fmt.Println(time.Since(t1))
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Print0")
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 9*time.Second)
    test(ctx)
    cancel()
    fmt.Println("Print3")
}

Since, official documentation says context with timeout gets cancelled automatically, none of the Print statements shouldn't work. But, getting final response as:
Print0
Print1
10s
Print2
10s
Print3



Context cancellation is not goroutine cancellation. You have to check if the context is canceled in the goroutine, and act accordingly.
func test1(ctx context.Context) {
    // Check if context canceled
    if ctx.Err()!=nil {
       fmt.Println("Canceled")
       return
    }
    fmt.Println("Print2")
}

This mechanism allows goroutines receive the context cancellation either through Context.Done() channel, or through Context.Err() method. Upon receiving this notification, the goroutine can cleanup and terminate correctly.

Burak's answer correctly states that context cancellation is not goroutine cancellation.
Put another way, when a context has a cancellation mechanism there must be one routine waiting on that cancellation and another routine which may (or may not) trigger that cancellation.
To try to make sense of this in the context of your example you could modify it to:
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func test1(ctx context.Context) {
    fmt.Println("Print2")
}

func test(ctx context.Context, delay time.Duration) {
    t1 := time.Now()
    done := make(chan struct{})

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(delay)
        close(done)
    }()
    select {
    case <-done:
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Println("timeout after", time.Since(t1))
        close(done)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Print1")
    fmt.Println(time.Since(t1))
    test1(ctx)
    fmt.Println(time.Since(t1))
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Print0")
    wait := 1 * time.Second
    timeout := 2 * time.Second
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), timeout)
    defer cancel()
    test(ctx, wait)
    fmt.Println("Print3")
}

playground
I make no claims about the quality of this code; this is not necessarily a good way to do this.  It is for illustration only
In addition to introducing a goroutine to perform the Sleep, I have added a timeout param to the test function, together with two variables (wait and timeout) to allow you to easily experiment with different scenarios.
With the modifications, the test function will wait for the delay period, simulating a long-running operation; a done channel is created, which is closed when this long-running operation is complete.
After starting the goroutine for the long-running operation, the test function waits for either that operation to complete or for the supplied context to be cancelled (i.e. the context timeout is triggered).
If delay is shorter than timeout, then the sleeping goroutine will complete before the context is cancelled, closing the done channel. Thereupon, the test function proceeds to output Print1 and Print2, etc.
If delay is longer than timeout, then the context will be cancelled before the long-running operation has been completed, causing the test function to output the timeout after message and return without completing any further processing.
The playground linked above is set with delay < timeout so all Print lines are output.
If you change delay to be > timeout then you will see only Print0 and Print3 (plus the additional timeout after message I have introduced).
I hope this is helpful to your understanding.
